# lowercase the text file from Input

Tags: python, counter

```
name = input('Enter a file name: ')
with open(name) as handle: 
    
    counts = dict()
    for line in handle :
        words = line.split()
        for word in words :
            counts[word] = counts.get(word,0) +1
    #Not sure what variable I should use to get all 4 the's
    
    bigcount = None
    bigword = None
    for word,count in counts.items() :
        if bigcount is None or count > bigcount:
            bigword = word
            bigcount = count
    
    print(bigword, bigcount)
```

I created a file named Frog.txt, Here’s essentially what it reads.

```
The little frog and the the the fox.
```

It resolves itself with "the 3", but I would like it to read "the 4"

Comment: Put `word = word.lower()` at the begining of the `for word in words:` loop.

Comment: BTW, there's a built-in `collections.Counter()` that does the counting. `counts = collections.Counter(word.lower() for word in handle.read().split())`